# Are there plans for further spelling reforms for German?

Tags: spelling

Are there any plans to reform the German orthography even more?

Comment: What did the new one improve in your opinion? I, for one, have plans to go back to the old one. Trouble is,while I never got used to it,  the new one made me forget the old one!

Comment: See also http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/

Comment: A question about plans is not "opinion-based", it asks for facts. So the reason for putting this on hold is wrong.

Comment: A question about plans is about unannounced future events. Maybe opinion-based is not the best way to put it but I believe this has been closed correctly.

Comment: @Jan A question about plans is about future events. There is nothing  opinion-based about the answers "Something has been announced" or "Nothing has been announced".

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-known statement by
Johanna Wanka,
now Federal Minister for Education and Research,
and formerly Minister for Science and Culture of the states of Brandenburg
and Lower Saxony
and president of the Kultusministerkonferenz,
that appeared in an [interview in "Spiegel" in January 2006](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-45168987.html):
*"The Ministers of Culture have long known that the spelling reform was wrong.
For reasons of state, it has not been withdrawn."*
(*„Die Kultusminister wissen längst, dass die Rechtschreibreform falsch war. Aus Gründen der Staatsräson ist sie nicht zurückgenommen worden.“*)

So, while there may indeed be a few people who are in favor of further
changes of the German orthography (I wouldn't call them improvements
myself),
it is very unlikely that such plans are supported by the current
political class.